# Executor.submit() returns null

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executor

I am working in a multithreaded environment with many methods to be called using Executors. The code works fine even for large data earlier, but it threw a null pointer exception once.
Here is the related parts of the code.

```
private ExecutorService crawlerTaskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CRAWLER_THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
private List<Future<Boolean>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();

futureList.add(crawlerTaskExecutor.submit(() -> fetchDocuments(siteUrl),Boolean.FALSE));
//Many other method calls are also present.

private boolean isCrawlerRunning() {
    boolean isRunning = Boolean.FALSE;
    if (Objects.nonNull(futureList)) {
        for (Future<Boolean> future : futureList) {
            if (!future.isDone()) {//got null pointer here.
                isRunning = Boolean.TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return isRunning;
}
```

I got a null pointer in line `if (!future.isDone())`. Now I am not getting why would the future be null? I understand that `crawlerTaskExecutor.submit` is returning null but why and when it can return null? And what could be done if it returns null?

I am not getting why this happened, this issue doesn't get produced earlier even with lots of run with 500k data and suddenly appeared.

Comment: I’ve never heard of ExecutorService.submit returning null.  You may want to add a check in the code to be sure it’s not null.  (Note:  use `false` and `true`, not Boolean.FALSE and Boolean.TRUE.  And use `futureList != null`, not Objects.nonNull(futureList).  Objects.nonNull is meant for stream filtering;  it’s not a replacement for basic operators.)

Comment: I feel like this might happen because of visibility issues(correctly publishing objects so that other threads could see them in a valid state[meeting all their invariants]) or because of thread safety issues or both.  For instance; List<Future<Boolean>> futureList = new ArrayList<>() is not safely published and it is not thread safe. Hence, multiple threads accessing that could produce interesting things. NOTE: If the array list is thread local, then this is not an issue. [in this case, a thread checks whether tasks it submitted finished and do not care other tasks of other threads]

Comment: private final ExecutorService crawlerTaskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CRAWLER_THREAD_POOL_SIZE); [final safely publishes], and try using a concurrent list instead of ArrayList. This might be,      private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Future<Void>>
            futureList = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();.

Comment: I do not know if you shutdown the ExecutorService but you might need to shutdown that as well. [Add a method to shutdown ExecutorService. You might use shutdown() method on it and await for termination]

Comment: You need to synchronize access to the list or protect it in some other way. Either wrap it with Collections.synchronizedList when you create it or use ConcurrentLinkedQueue or CopyOnWriteArrayList. I would start with synchronization.